# GetOracleWhere method in DevExpress adding quotes to query causing SQL error

Tags: c#, oracle, devexpress

Code Snippet:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterColumns))
         {
            filterColumns = filterColumns.Replace("[", "[lower(").Replace("]", ")]");
            CriteriaOperator op = CriteriaOperator.Parse(filterColumns);
            string filter = String.Empty;
            if (dbUtils.DbType == 1)
            {
               filter = CriteriaToWhereClauseHelper.GetOracleWhere(op, false);
               filter = filter.ToLower();
            }
```

Issue: The above is implemented in C# and In previous DevExpress versions I was not getting this issue, and I recently upgraded, but I think the GetOracleWhere is forcing quotations on my query that is being built. So for example, from the above it generates a query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) dataCount  
                              FROM (SELECT r.* 
                                                          FROM rmrtemplate r
                                                          WHERE templatename IS NOT NULL AND (instr("lower(templatename)", '0022') > 0)) tmptable
```

I believe the line causing the issue is: filter = CriteriaToWhereClauseHelper.GetOracleWhere(op, false);

The issue lies on the “lower(templatename)”, this is causing a sql error to be generated since the query is throwing an invalid identifier there, from what I am assuming is that the query is recognizing lower as part of a string and not as an actual query function, what are some workarounds with this?

Since in my CriteriaToWhereClauseHelper Class for that specific method, all I have is:

```
      public static string GetOracleWhere(CriteriaOperator op);
      public static string GetOracleWhere(CriteriaOperator op, bool forceQuotesOnOperandProperties);
      public static string GetOracleWhere(CriteriaOperator op, Func<OperandProperty, string> propertyFormatter);
```

I tried forcefully removing the quotations but even that didn't work with something along the lines of:

```
               filter = Regex.Replace(filter, "\"(lower\\(templatename\\))\"", "$1"); // removes the quotation marks around lower(templatename)
               filter = filter.Replace("\"", ""); // Removes any remaining quotation marks                                             
               //filter = filter;
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my own issue; using the

```
filter = filter.Replace("\"", ""); // Removes any remaining quotation marks
```

was the right idea, but there were two methods that needed to have this line of code in order to fix it. I updated 1 method while neglecting the other which painted my demise.